# Android App to download JSON data from server using Asyntask

Tags: android, json, download

Currently i am building an app to display data get from server. 
The requirement is to download data (JSON format) from server and insert into phone's local DB.

The process on getting the data is:
The app has to call an url to go to json service (eg. A) and grab another url (http://www.XXX.json) to go to another JSON service (B) to get the exact data.

A
    {
      "return_code" : 0,
      "return_msg" : "OK",
      "num_files" : 1,
      "total_size_bytes" : 1691857,
      "files" : {
          "0" : {
               "size_bytes" : 1691857,
               "url" : "http://www.XXX.json"
          }
       },
       "request" : "http://www......."
     }

B
        {"tables":
         {"test": [
         [ "30094394", "23432", "TESTING", "33342", "", "", "" ]
         ]
            ......
         }
         }

I have tried AsynTask but I not sure whether the approach is correct or not? The solution i need is to download and insert data into DB which running in background.
I hope can get advice from some expert for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is a good way to achieve this.
Search for "async task json". You should find plenty of tutorials.
My first attempt would be to write two separate AsyncTasks, the first that downloads the JSON from service A und upon finishing launches the second AsyncTask, passing in the URL that it received from service A. The second AsyncTask then loads the JSON from said URL and saves it into the DB (all in `doInBackground`).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get Data from Server to android app.

1)Add Internet permission in Manifest.xml file

2)pass the URL of JSON file to asynctask as params and get that data on doInBackground().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

3)Get all Data as Response from doInBackground() using HTTpClient 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

4)Parse data receive from doInBackground() as result in onPostExecute().
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

5)Perform operation with data what you want